The DOCKER-USER chain disappeared after restarting iptables and Docker
my docker version
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.6
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.7
  Git commit:       1a79695
  Built:            Mon Sep  4 12:32:17 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false

I executed  systemctl restart iptables
I know this will clear the Docker chains
so I do systemctl restart docker to add docker chains to iptables
but now i find the docker-user chains is missing
no docker-user chains
and no docker-user policy in forward chains
 iptables -nvL FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 15 packets, 2668 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  483  190K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  182  130K ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    4   240 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  253 53219 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0


iptables -nvL DOCKER-USER
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.


I am trying to manually create DOCKER-USER chains,and restart docker
iptables -N DOCKER-USER
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN

and restart docker
but it did not add DOCKER-USER to FORWARD
